# Pythonのdb.create_all() でデータベース作成方法について

Tags: python, python3, flask

#### 前提・実現したいこと

下記のコードのようにpython:Flaskを使ってデータベースを作成したいですが、
`db.create_all()` のコマンドを入れてもデータベースが作成されません。

code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SLQAlCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///todo.db'
db=SQLAlchemy(app)

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(30),nullable=False)
    detail = db.Column(db.String(100))
    due = db.Column(db.DateTime,nullable=False)

@app.route('/')

def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

エラーのSQLメモリ関係していますでしょうか。

```
"sqlite:///:memory:".
```

#### 出力結果

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\test\Documents\TODO-APP> python
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from app import db
C:\Users\test\Documents\TODO-APP\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:851: UserWarning: Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\test\Documents\TODO-APP\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:872: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
>>> db.create_all()
```

#### 補足情報（Python/ツールのバージョンなど）

Python 3.9.5/Windows10の仮想環境で利用しています。

もしわかる方いれば、教えていただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純なタイプミスが原因に見えます。(質問のコードでは S**LQ**AlCHEMY_DATABASE_URI になっている)

**誤:**

```py
app.config['SLQAlCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///todo.db'
```

**正:**

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///todo.db'
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。全然気づきませんでした。。失礼しました。上記の方法で作成できました。